# reducible polynomial over the finite field of order 11

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Is $f = x^2 + y^2$ reducible polynomial over the finite field $f$ of order 11?

Comment: As there are only a finite  number of possibilities, which ones have you excluded so far?

Comment: A good idea is if something seems like it could be homework question is to try include any own attempts you make or show some effort. Otherwise there is an increased risk of question to be closed or at least get downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $11 \equiv 3$ mod $4$, hence $11$ cannot be written as sum of two squares, or equivalently, $-1$ is not a square in $\mathbb{F}_{11}$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, I did not get the idea. could you please explain more why you talk about the inverse and $f$ is it reducible or irreducible over $f_{1_1}$?. Also, $f$ is going to be reducible or irreducible if it used over another fields, say $f_7$ or $f_{1_3}$?. many thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $p$ be a prime. If $f$ is reducible, then it would split in two linear monic polynomials, say $f=(x+ay)(x+by)$, with $a,b \in \mathbb{F}_p$, hence $a+b=0$ and $ab=1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$. This implies that $-1=a^2$. So $f$ splits iff $-1$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_p$ and this holds iff $p \equiv 1$ mod $4$.

Comment: Many thanks Nicky.